# Add cc: recipient in var options IF condition in sheet is met

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

I am VERY limited in my knowledge of java/google scripts.

Below is a snippet of my code for my sendEmail script. I currently have one cc: recipient, but would like to add a second cc: recipient if a condition is met in my google sheet. eg: row[18]=Yes. I would also need the second recipient email pulled from the google sheet. Is this possible?? How can I accomplish this??

Extra points if I can pull in the email address from another sheet.

```
if (Sdate >= SsheetDate && row[1] != "Fire"){
    if (row[17] != EMAIL_SENT) {
       var emailAddress = row[13]; 
       var file1 = DriveApp.getFileById(row[14]);
       var file2 = DriveApp.getFileById("");
       var options = {cc: row[16], replyTo: row[16],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Sdate >= SsheetDate && row[1] != "Fire" && row[17] != EMAIL_SENT && row[18] == "Yes") {
       var emailAddress = row[13]; 
       var file1 = DriveApp.getFileById(row[14]);
       var file2 = DriveApp.getFileById("");
       var options = {cc: row[16], replyTo: row[16],
```